# Pasar props a un componente rendeizado por React Router dentro de un Switch

Tags: reactjs

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación sencilla donde no quiero utilizar react con redux.

Manejo la autenticacion con firebase, tengo un componente Header que se ve en todas las rutas donde administro el login y luego paso es usuario al componete Route.

Es aquí donde quiero gestionar el usuario y poder enviárselo a otros componentes pero no logro pasar el User desde Routes al Componente Super_Admin

ya intente `<Route  path="/administar_cuentas" render={(props) => <SuperAdmin {...props} actualUser={this.actualUser}/>}`

pero al intentar leerlo (this.props.actualUser) me responde

> SuperAdmin.js:20 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'actualUser' of undefined

¿como podria pasar props a un componente rendeizado por React Router dentro de un Switch?

adjunto codigo

Router.js

```
export default class Router extends Component {
  state= {
    user: null 
   }

   actualUser= this.state.user;

  sessionUser = (user) =>{

   if(user !=null ){
    this.setState({
      user: user
    });
    console.log(user.displayName);
   }
  }
    render() {
        return (
          <BrowserRouter>

            <Header sessionUser={this.sessionUser} />

            <Container fluid={false}  >
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>  

                <Route  path="/administar_cuentas" render={(props) => <SuperAdmin {...props} actualUser={this.actualUser}/>}
                />      
              </Switch>
            </Container>
          </BrowserRouter>  
        );
    }
}
```

SuperAdmin.js

```
export default class SuperAdmin extends Component {
    state= {
        user: "",
    }


    componentWillMount(){
      // validar si existe session abierta

    }


    imprimir(){
      console.log(this.props.actualUser);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Row className="mt-3  ">

              <ListaCategorias user={this.state.user}  />

              <Col sm={7} className="recuadro ml-4">
                  <h1 className="text-center"> Datos empresas</h1>
                  <Button onClick={this.imprimir} >Imprimir</Button>
             </Col>
              <AuthUserContext.Consumer>
              {authUser =>
                authUser ? <h1>Loguaeado</h1> : <h1>Iniciar Sesion</h1>
              }
            </AuthUserContext.Consumer>
            </Row>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: El error te dice que no puede leer la propiedad `actualUser` de `undefined`, o sea que `this.props` es `undefined`, esto se debe a que `this` hace parte de otro scope por lo que puedes cambiarla a una ___arrow function___ o cambiar tu botón por uno así: `<Button onClick={this.imprimir.bind(this)}>Imprimir</Button>` y de esta forma funcionaría

Comment: @GermanAlzate No es recomendable hacer un `bind` dentro de los renders por cuestión de performance. Es mejor usar métodos arrow.

Comment: Tienes razón @gugadev, también puede hacerlo en el constructor, lo cual es mucho más optimo incluso que un _arrow function_ ya que al momento de transpilar no crea referencias adicionales

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dentro de lo `render`, **this** hace referencia a la instancia misma, pero es distinto en funciones:

> Los métodos de clase en JavaScript no son *bindeados* por defecto.

Lo que necesitas realizar es hacer un binding explícito:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.imprimir = this.imprimir.bind(this)
}
```

O usar arrow functions:

```
imprimir = () => { ... }
```

Comment: Gracias..., esto soluciono todo , aun no entiendo bien el manejo de los scope y el concepto del .bind(this) pero empezare a empaparme del tema, pues como dice  @gugadev  al momento de transpilar no crea referencias adicionales mejorando el rendimiento de la aplicaion

Comment: Dependiendo si transpilas a ES5. Si generas bundles para ES6 no habría impacto en performance.